# Поэлементная обработка массива, сортировка массива

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, сортировка, foreach

Есть задача с помощью поэлементной обработки массива foreach() отсортировать массив. Я не могу понять, как это можно сделать. Я использовал метод пузырьков, но ведь он работает не с элементами, а с массивом. Вот фрагмент кода:

```
void foreach(){
        double temp;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sz - 1; i++) {
         for (size_t j = 0; j < sz - i - 1; j++) {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `foreach` в C++ нет. Вы имеете в виду цикл по диапазону (`for(auto elem: container)`) или  стандартный алгоритм `for_each`? То, что пишете вы - это просто функция сортировки под названием `foreach` :))

Comment: Да, цикл по диапазону, Вы правы) Я не могу ещё правильно формулировать мысль. Нужно чтобы он использовал именно этот цикл

Comment: Harry,Вы не правы foreach в C++ есть, начиная с версии 11. Создайте два итератора на элементы (текущий и предидущий) и переставляйте элементы, как обычно, вместо индексов используя итераторы.

Comment: @Виктор Не сочтите за труд, приведите мне код - без хитростей :) - в котором заработает именно `foreach` - не цикл по диапазону, и не `for_each`, о которых я упоминал в своем комментарии, на который вы, по сути, ссылаетесь.

Comment: Да, признаю, что foreach(var, container) возвращает переменную, но не итератор, а это не позволяет изменить значение переменной в контейнере через var.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скажем так - в рамках обращения к *единственному* элементу я не вижу никакой возможности это сделать. Поскольку само понятие отсортированности к единственному элементу неприменимо.

Но поскольку в цикл по диапазону обязательно передается *контейнер*, то мы им воспользуемся. [Им и сортировкой вставками](https://ideone.com/GII4Ec):

```
int a[] = { 3, 5, 12, 1, 48, 2, 4 };

for(auto& i: a) swap(i,*min_element(&i,end(a)));
```

Если это не годится - ну, тогда я не знаю, что от вас хотят... :(

Comment: я думаю, что под поэлементной обработкой имеется ввиду не сравнение с остальной частью массива, а наоборот:.  к_тый элемент сравнивается с элементами a[0]...a[k]

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Это всего лишь тот же пример "наизнанку", в котором явный цикл будет внутри.

Comment: Ну да, хотя тут только можно догадываться только...